# How to release the memory of cocoa web view?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

I find that my app holds a lot of memory when the web view has already been released.Because my app needs to load many webpages.This is my release function called in the dealloc method.

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];    
[[_webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
[_webView stopLoading:nil];
[_webView removeFromSuperview];
[_webView setResourceLoadDelegate:nil];
[_webView setFrameLoadDelegate:nil];
[_webView release];
_webView = nil;
```

But there is nothing happen when do this.It's still a lot of memory being holder.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

- Run Build and Analyze and fix every error it generates.
- Use [Instrument's Leaks tool](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial) to find memory leaks
- Audit your code to make sure you aren't keeping a retained reference somewhere.

Comment: I have already used the Instruments and found no memory leaks.I create the category of cocoa webview and add a cealrForDealloc function.The memory leaks looks like a lithe improved.